# Filter results by integer with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkbox, filtering

I have an MVC project and I'm using Entity Framework.

I have some data in the database that needs filtering by an integer variable (time) using checkboxes. I am getting an error message:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'time' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String[], Int32)' in 'LazyRecipe.DAL.RecipesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

How can I filter the data?

```
// GET: Recipes
    public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string[] FilteredsearchString, int time)
    {   
        IQueryable recipes;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            recipes = db.Recipes.Include("Ingredients");
        }
        else
        {
            FilteredsearchString = searchString.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            // "string" can be lowercase.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", FilteredsearchString));

            // ... "String" can be uppercase.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", FilteredsearchString));

            recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => FilteredsearchString.Contains(i.Ingredi‌​entName)));
        }

        switch(time)
        {


            case 30:
            recipes = db.Recipes.Where(c => c.Time.CompareTo(time) <= 30);
            break;

            case 60:
            recipes = db.Recipes.Where(c => c.Time.CompareTo(time) <= 60);
            break;

            case 61:
            recipes = db.Recipes.Where(c => c.Time.CompareTo(time) >= 61);
            break;

            default:
                recipes = db.Recipes;
                break;
        }


        return View(recipes);
    }
```

Comment: The message is self explanatory - your not passing a value for the `time` parameter.

Comment: `Where(c => c.Time.CompareTo(time) <= 30)`  – I think you meant `Where(c => c.Time <= 30);` ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I actually wanted! What should I pass in the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 30:
    recipes = db.Recipes.Where(c => c.Time.CompareTo(time) <= 30);
    break;
```

I think what you meant to do here is to simply compare the `c.Time` with the constant `30`. So you would simply do `.Where(c => c.Time <= 30)` or `.Where(c => c.Time <= time)` since `time` is of the same value as the value you are comparing with.

Note that you should not start your query back at `db.Recipes` all the time. By doing `recipes = db.Recipes.Where(…)` you are overwriting any query you have previously already set up for `recipes`. For example, the `.Include("Ingredients")` from the first `if` in your code would be overwritten then.

Instead, just keep calling the query methods on `recipes` to keep refinining it:

```
recipes = recipes.Where(c => c.Time <= 30);
```

As for your `switch` statement, since you keep comparing the time against the value of `time` in each of those constant cases, you do not need to write it three times. You can just check whether `time` is `30`, `60` or `61` and then compare against `time`.

In total, your method could look like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string[] FilteredsearchString, int time)
{
    IQueryable recipes = db.Recipes.Include("Ingredients");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        recipes = recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (time == 30 || time == 60 || time == 61)
    {
        recipes = recieps.Where(c => c.Time <= time);
    }

    return View(recipes);
}
```

Note that you should revise your `searchString` logic. It does not really make sense to me that you pass both a `searchString` and a `FilteredsearchString` array which you *then* fill by splitting the `searchString`? You probably meant the `FilteredsearchString` to be a local variable here?

Comment: This might correct some of OP's code, but it has nothing at all to do with the question and the exception that is being thrown